# Who is that cowgirl appearing during the Columbia Pictures intro?

Tags: marvel, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018), this is how she looks:

[image: Cowgirl on top of Columbia Pictures intro]

Who is that cowgirl appearing during the Columbia Pictures intro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Cowgirl* is from Columbia Pictures' 1965's American western musical comedy film "[**Cat Ballou**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_Ballou)" starring Jane Fonda and Lee Marvin.

Here's the intro to the **Cat Ballou (1965)** musical comedy:

Comment: FWIW, there's a more lengthy freeze-frame analysis at http://cartoonresearch.com/index.php/the-trippy-columbia-logo-art-in-spider-man-into-the-spiderverse/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yeah. I saw that too. But I thought that this video would be more useful as it kinda is what the intro in Into the Spider-verse used.